# Sending XML from one MVC4 server to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webclient

I'm trying to send XML data from one MVC4 server (server 1) to another (server 2)

Simplified code below. My code works up to a point - the server 2 method gets called but the data does not seem to be getting passed through.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong (I think the root of the problem is that I'm not understanding how to convert the xml data properly and how it should be accepted by server 2).

I have also tried using `client.UploadString` and also WebRequest (which I'd rather not use as it seems v cumbersome) without any success.

Within server 1 - Used to send XML data to server2

```
public void SubmitClicked(String answersJsonStr)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SubmitClicked() " + answersJsonStr);

    XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(answersJsonStr, "Root");
    var answersXml = node.ToString();
    //This gives: "<Root>\r\n  <question1>answer 1</question1>\r\n</Root>"

    String fullUrl = "http://localhost:61728/SubmitSurveyAnswers";

    WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
    byte[] bret = client.UploadData(fullUrl, "POST",
        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(answersXml));

    Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret));
}
```

Method in controller in server2

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSurveyAnswers(String answersXml)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SubmitSurveyAnswers() " + answersXml);
    //answersXML seems to be null
    return Content("answers accepted", "text/html");
}
```

Note the server2 is just a simulation model - the real receiver of XML will be provided by another company.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing your content type header

```
public void SubmitClicked(String answersJsonStr)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SubmitClicked() " + answersJsonStr);

    XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(answersJsonStr, "Root");
    var answersXml = node.ToString();
    //This gives: "<Root>\r\n  <question1>answer 1</question1>\r\n</Root>"

    String fullUrl = "http://localhost:61728/SubmitSurveyAnswers";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
      client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      byte[] bret = client.UploadData(fullUrl, "POST", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(answersXml));

      Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

add in: "answersXml=" + answersXml,

[ValidateInput(false)],

plus testydonkey's addition....

```
public void SubmitClicked(String answersJsonStr)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SubmitClicked() " + answersJsonStr);

    XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(answersJsonStr, "Root");
    var answersXml = node.ToString();
    //This gives: "<Root>\r\n  <question1>answer 1</question1>\r\n</Root>"

    String fullUrl = "http://localhost:61728/SubmitSurveyAnswers";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
      client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      byte[] bret = client.UploadData(fullUrl, "POST",
          System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("answersXml=" + answersXml)));

      Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret));
    }
}




    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitSurveyAnswers(String answersXml)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SubmitSurveyAnswers() " + answersXml);
        return Content("answers accepted ", "text/html");
    }
```